# Get the references from a .bib file to a separate chapter in the sub directory

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, pdftex

Actually I am new in LaTeX. I want to get print the bibliography in every chapter. I have tried but failed. My files structure are given below:

In the folder `texfiles` there are one sub folder named `chapters` and two files one main `.tex` file named `main.tex` and another `.bib` file named `bibliography.bib` file.

The subfolder `chapters` contains two `.tex` files they are `chapter01.tex` and `chapter02.tex`.

The directory `texfiles` contains :

1.

`main.tex`:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
 \usepackage{biblatex}
 \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
 \bibliography{bibliography}
 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
  \begin{document}
  \author{Author's Name}
  \title{Simple Book Example}
  \date{January 2017}

  \frontmatter
   \maketitle
  \tableofcontents

  \mainmatter
   \include{./chapters/chapter01}
   \include{./chapters/chapter02}

   \backmatter

   \end{document}
```

2.

`bibliography.bib`:

```
 @book{id1,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    date = {date},
    publisher={aaaaaaa},
    year={2017}
}

@book{id2,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    date = {date},
    publisher={sdddddddds},
    year={2017}
}
```

and the subdirectory `chapters` contains as follows:

1.

`chapter01.tex`:

```
\chapter{Title of chapter 1}
some text of chapter 1

\section{Title of section}
some text of section of chapter 1

\cite{id1,id2}
\printbibliography
```

2.

`chapter02.tex`:

```
\chapter{Title of chapter 2}
some text of chapter 2

\section{Title of section}
some text of section of chapter 2

\cite{id1,id2}
\printbibliography
```

I am using 'Texstudio' compiler in Linuxmint OS.
Please help me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The `natbib` package is incompatible with `biblatex` (`chapterbib` is similarly incompatible with `biblatex`), you will have to use one or the other.

Comment: @DB I have removed natbib and recompiled but again shows error : 'Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid. \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}'. I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Just remove the `\bibliographystyle` line, `biblatex` does not use the `\bibliographystyle` command to set the style (take a look at the `biblatex` manual on CTAN or run `texdoc biblatex` to get your local copy for information on styles with `biblatex`)

Comment: @DB I dit it but references do not get print in the pdf file

Comment: Are you running `biber` (the default backend for `biblatex`)? Take a look at [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162) and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/106162) for reference.

Comment: Do you really want the bibliography repeated in every chapter? Or do you want a bibliography in each chapter?

Comment: I what bibliography in each chapter

Comment: @Primo you will need to make some changes to get an independent bibliography in each chapter, but you should see some kind of bibliography with the necessary changes I've already commented on, if you're not it suggests you've not got the `latex biber latex` compilation sequence working, did you take a look at the questions that I linked to?

Answer (score 1):

With the option `refsegment=chapter` for `biblatex` you can get what you want.

Then you can write

```
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=first bib]
```

and option `segment=\therefsegment` gives you a bibliography for only cited bib entries in the current segment.

Please see the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{id1,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    date = {date},
    publisher={aaaaaaa},
    year={2017}
}

@book{id2,
    author = {author},
    title = {title},
    date = {date},
    publisher={sdddddddds},
    year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[%
  refsegment=chapter, % <===============================================
  natbib
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

\author{Author's Name}
\title{Simple Book Example}
\date{January 2017}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter


\chapter{Title of chapter 1}
some text of chapter 1

\section{Title of section}
some text of section of chapter 1

\cite{id1,id2}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=first bib] % <==========


\chapter{Title of chapter 2}
some text of chapter 2

\cite{id1}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,title=second bib] % <=========

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

and the two resulting bibliographies:

[image: first bobliography]

and

[image: second bibliography]